# Is it possible to dynamically delete data from Mysql in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete all rows in all the tables associated with one client. I've tried the query in Mysql and it works just fine. It also works in PHP when I manually enter client_id. But nothing happens when I try using a dynamic variable populated from jQuery. No error and nothing gets deleted. I've checked if there is data in the variable and yes there is. So it comes to my understanding it is impossible to delete data dynamically?

**script**

```
<script>
      $('#deleteClientModal').on('show.bs.modal',function (dclient){
                              var button = $(dclient.relatedTarget);
                              //get data
                              var deleteClientid = button.data('clientidentification');
                              //append to modal
                              var modal = $(this);
                              modal.find('#deleteClientid').val(deleteClientid );
                        });
</script>
```

**modal.php**

```
    <button data-clientidentification="<?=$client['id'];?>" title="Delete Client" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteClientModal"></button>


        <form id="removeclient" method="POST" action="core/query.php">
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="deleteClientModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
//short Modal for example
                  <input name="removeClientid " id="deleteClientid" type="text" class="formBlock"  value=""/> 
            <input name="removeClient" id="submit" type="submit" class="formBlock btn btn-success"  value="Yes"/>
             <button type="button" class="close btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
              </div>
        </form>
```

**query.php**

```
//deleteClient
  if(isset($_POST['removeClient'])){
//retrieve value from form
 $removeClientid = $_POST['removeClientid'];
//update clients by deleting the row
$deleteClient="DELETE `clients`, `projects`, `employeeprojects`, `employeeprojects_conversation` FROM `clients` INNER JOIN `projects` ON clients.id=projects.client_id INNER JOIN `employeeprojects` ON projects.project_id=employeeprojects.project_id INNER JOIN `employeeprojects_conversation` ON employeeprojects.project_id=employeeprojects_conversation.project_id WHERE clients.id='$removeClientid'";
//execute query
if ($db->query($deleteClient) === TRUE) {
    //reset tables to 1 if table empty
 header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
 exit;
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . $db->error;
}
$db->close();
  }
```

Comment: You might want to remove the single quotes, if clients.id number, might be that

Comment: For this to work, you will need to use AJAX. JS-variables won't be available to PHP, even when added to the DOM. Make the form, and display it via PHP/HTML, and then use the jQuery-bit and send the ID via AJAX to a processing PHP-file.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie: well that's kinda weird because how come I can use the JS-variables in an insert statement and not in a delete statement? It works  with all my insert and update statements.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie: if you want to post an answer to demonstrate what you"re saying that would be nice. You can get the credits. I wrote an ajax function that does not work :   `$('#submit').click(function() {
                              var deleteClientid = $(this).data('clientidentification');
                            $.ajax({
                            url: 'core/query.php',
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {deleteClientid: deleteClientid}
                            });
                            });`